# Retrieving a DBpedia resource by its string name with SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia, foaf

I am trying to get the resource describing country Romania by the country name with this query:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE {
     ?x foaf:name 'Romania'
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fx+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%3Fx+foaf%3Aname+%27Romania%27%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

However, it does not retrieve anything. How can I get the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Romania` (`:Romania`) by the string `'Romania'`.
If I want to retrieve the name of the country by the country resource I use the following query which works fine:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE {
     :Romania foaf:name ?x
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fx+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++++++++%3ARomania+foaf%3Aname+%3Fx%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 10):

This ought to do it:

```
SELECT ?c
WHERE {
  ?c a dbo:Country ;
     foaf:name "Romania"@en .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?c dbo:dissolutionYear ?y }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fc%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fc+a+dbo%3ACountry+%3B%0D%0A+++++foaf%3Aname+%22Romania%22%40en+.%0D%0A++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B+%3Fc+dbo%3AdissolutionYear+%3Fy+%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The critical quirk here is that `"Romania"` with no language tag is different from `"Romania"@en`. And then you also have a bunch of historical states that were also called Romania, so we filter out any of those that have years of dissolution. DBpedia's data-completeness for years of dissolution isn't terrific, but all the Romanian ones, at least, are marked.

Comment: @glennmcdonald Interestingly, some years later, someone has used the country infobox template on the Romania page, so the results also include [Commemorative_coins_of_Romania](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Commemorative_coins_of_Romania)!

Comment: Even more interestingly, the `dissolutionDate` property was important in answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6392515/1281433) as well.