# Sparql query gone wrong cause of incorrect geo onto + inexistence in results of a property I required

Tags: php, sparql

I'm using ARC2 library for php to issue sparql queries, and i got stuck on this issue (I don't think it has something to do with the lib).

This query works just fine - in my app, and in dbpedia snorql:

```
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

SELECT * WHERE {
?c rdf:type dbo:Country;
foaf:name "someCountryName"@en.
}
```

On the other hand, this query doesn't work:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?c rdf:type dbo:Country;
foaf:name "someCountryName"@en;
geo:lat ?lat.
}
```

Note: the query is done using the same prefixes as listed above.
I just need to take lat & long of a country. I could also try Freebase, but i really need to make it work here. The 2nd query works in snorql, can't see why it doesn't also work in my app?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Now that the 8 hours are over, could you split the question and answer? And make the title question a question again? (Going for no unanswered SPARQL questions)

Comment: The `dissolutionDate` trick for Romania also appeared in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5921884/1281433).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note:** This text was provided by @IrinaM, but put into the question as [a revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6392515/2) because of the eight hour limit.  It's now much later and the suggestion that @IrinaM post as an answer hasn't been acted upon.  Here's a slightly edited CW answer containing that text.*

There are several mistakes in the code in the question.

1. The 2<sup>nd</sup> query (the one that didn't “work”) would return several results. If I searched countries with `foaf:name "Romania"`, it would return `"Communist Romania"`, `"Wallachian Romania"`, `"Romania"`, etc. Out of these results, only one would have `geo:lat` and `geo:long`.
   Basically, when a required property isn't satisfied by all the results, then no results will be returned.
2. The wrong ontology is used for `geo`; it should be `<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>`.
3. The other odd results need to be filtered out, to only keep the desired unique results. In this case, filtering after the *inexistence* of `dbpedia-owl:dissolutionDate` works.
   Exact matches of foaf:name using `FILTER (?name="someCountryName"^^xsd:string)` do not work.

Here's code that retrieves successfully the latitude and longitude values for a given country (beware, some other filters may be needed when searching for the right country):

```php
//setup prefixes
$prefixes = 'PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
';    
//query no. 1 - find out "right" country - hoping for a unique result
$q1 = $prefixes.'SELECT ?c WHERE {
?c rdf:type dbo:Country;
foaf:name "'.$userPreferences->country.'"@en. 
OPTIONAL {?c dbo:dissolutionDate ?x}
FILTER(!bound(?x))}';
//note: $userPreferences->country represents a country entered by the user in an input

//query no. 2 - find out long & lat
$q2 = $prefixes.'SELECT * WHERE {
<'.$countryReturned.'> geo:lat ?lat;
geo:long ?long.
}';
//note: $countryReturned represents the URI of the "unique" country my 1st query
//retrieved, we use it directly.
```

For those passionate about ARC2 PHP lib, this is how to make the queries (note:don't forget to include the *ARC2.php* file):

```php
$dbpediaEndpoint = array('remote_store_endpoint' =>'http://dbpedia.org/sparql');
$dbpediaStore = ARC2::getRemoteStore($dbpediaEndpoint);
$rows1 = $dbpediaStore->query($q1,'rows');
var_dump($rows1); //to see quick results
```